# Unfortunately, "Register" has stoppped working

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, usb, logcat

I am working in IntelliJ IDEA and due to low specifications of my PC i.e, 2GB RAM I cannot run emulator , I have fixed all the errors in XML and java files and my Project is building and syncing absolutely fine but when i build the apk and install it on my phone it displays - :

> "Unfortunately, "Register" has stopped."

- I cannot take my LogCat out as, my CPU does not support VT-x and USB debugging is not working while ADB Integration is turned on, and my PC is not able to sense the USB cable connected between phone and PC. I have turned on the USB Debugging Option from the Developer Options on my phone.
- I typed `gradlew build --stacktrace` in the terminal and build successfully finished without giving any error.
  Is there any other way i can fix "`Unfortunately, 'Register' has stopped`"
  Any help will be highly appreciated
  Regards

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are using a physical phone to run your app without the possibility of using ADB to read logcat.

Try using a logcat reader app on your device, like CatLog: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat